# How do I make 2 checkboxes, that if for example one is checked and then you try to check the other it cancel the first one?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 checkboxes in my code:
`<input type = "checkbox" id = "soundyes" name = "soundyes" value = "soundyes">`

and

`<input type = "checkbox" id = "soundno" name = "soundno" value = "soundno">`

Is it possible that if for example, a person checked the "soundyes" one (soundyes.checked == true) and then tries to check the "soundno" one, it makes the first checkbox ("soundyes") unchecked (soundyes.checked == false) in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why dont you just use [radio button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Add an event listener to each button, that unchecks the other button.

Comment: `if (soundyes.checked) { soundno.checked = false; }`

Comment: Or more simply `soundno.checked = !soundyes.checked;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the handle the change event on both checkboxes.

```js
function uncheck(input){
    input.checked = false;
}
let no = document.querySelector("#soundno")
let yes = document.querySelector("#soundyes")
yes.addEventListener("click", e=>{
  uncheck(no)
});
no.addEventListener("click", e=>{
    uncheck(yes);
})
```

```html
Checkbox 1: <input type = "checkbox" id = "soundyes" name = "soundyes" value = "soundyes">


Checkbox 2: <input type = "checkbox" id = "soundno" name = "soundno" value = "soundno">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const y = document.querySelector('#yes');
const n = document.querySelector('#no');

const both = [y, n];
both.map(c => c.addEventListener('change', e => {
  both.filter(c => e.target !== c)[0].checked = !e.target.checked;
}));
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="yes" checked /> yes
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="no"/> no
</label>
```

---

---

This should work